# Atlassian Bamboo and static artifact and other bad practice with continuous delivery

Tags: bamboo, bitbucket-server, continuous-delivery, artifact

After hour of search, I can't find a way to insert a static file in a build plan.

I mean by static file, a simple txt file that is not in the repository (Git) and don't come from another build (artifact).

This let me wonder if it is a bad practice to use file that don't come from repo or other build.

Can someone explain why? Or tell me how to do it?

Comment: We finally opted for :
    CAT << EOF
    ...filecontent...
    EOF

Answer (score 1):

Where does this file come from?  You could easily have a file on the host that bamboo is running on and use it in the build.  You could also pull a file down from S3 relatively easy.

Comment: It was a file we upload when we start the parametised build.

Comment: I'm a little lost regarding how the file is related to the build.  Are you uploading via a web ui to the somewhere on the build host? Is the build your kicking off grabbing the file at build time?

Comment: The file is provided when we start the build. There is a script that use this file. Many user with different use case have their own script they can update at will and upload it when needed.